# Pygame window keeps crashing with no error message

Tags: python

My program appears to run fine in the "python shell" but the pygame window opens and stays on a blank screen not showing anything. any interaction with the pygame window crashes it, making it stop responding and asking if I would like to close it or not.
My aim was to make a red box with two black lines making an x in it to represent the red exit button on most computer programs.
I'm new to python and have been learning from programarcadegames.com. I've tried to copy and paste their code into an empty python document and it runs fine, I don't think my program does anything different in terms of the admin, yet it refuses to run.

Any advice would be appreciated whether you're solving the overall problem or not, as I'm still quite new 'round these parts, :)

Here is the program:

```
# Imports
import pygame
pygame.init()
import math
import sys
import os


# Setting variables and constants
PI = (math.pi)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
LYELLOW = (255, 255, 165)
# (Other colours removed for simplicity)

size = (1050, 750)
done = False
page = 0

test = 0


# Other admin
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)
pygame.display.set_caption("Coursework Program, Benjamin Youell-Wright")
clock = pygame.time.Clock()


# Main Program
while done == False:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            done = True


    while page == 0:
        test = 0
        
    
    while page == 1:
        test = 0
        
    
    while page == 2:
        test = 0
        
    
    while page == 3:
        test = 0
        
    
    while page == 4:
        test = 0
    
    
    screen.fill(WHITE)

    pygame.draw.rect(screen, RED,[775,595,20,20],2)
    
    pygame.draw.line(screen, BLACK, [779, 579], [791, 591], 1)
    pygame.draw.line(screen, BLACK, [779, 579], [791, 591], 1)
    
    pygame.display.flip()
    
    clock.tick(20)
    
pygame.quit()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a while loop inside your main loop that runs infinitely.

```
  while page == 0:
    test = 0
```

This just keeps setting test to 0 forever. You never actually reach the point where you flip the display. Remove these while loops and it should work.

Comment: Thanks, that was delaying me for hours. Such a simple and obvious solution yet I couldn't quite figure out the problem. I have now noticed that my exit button is in the wrong place, but that is easily fixed.

Answer (score 1):

There is an infinite loop in the main loop, which prevents the program from proceeding properly.